# Non-HID Mouse driver on NT

Tags: mouse, driver, hid, nt

I'm looking to write a custom touchpad driver for my laptop, as its support under Windows is abysmal.  I have the protocol figured out and I'm ready to go ahead and implement it, but I'm a bit confused as to how to go about it.  It's a multitouch touchpad, so I'd like to support the Windows Touch interfaces in addition to standard mouse support, but the examples in the WDK (Elotouch being the most relevant one) only show HID support.  In my Googling around, I discovered someone mentioning that the proper way to handle this is to write a shim driver that will expose HID from the low-level protocol, but I couldn't find good information on where to start with that.

What examples (WDK or otherwise) should I take a look at and is the HID shim the right way to go about this?  I'm looking to target Vista+ at the least, XP would be nice as well.

Thanks

Edit: A bit of clarification.  The touchpad is USB but non-HID.  Also, if the HID shim is the best way to go, can I use KMDF there, or do I have to go WDM?  Most of my experience is WDM, but I'm not sure which way to go.

Comment: If your target is Vista+, maybe XP, why does your question title refrence NT?

Comment: After giving your question a little more thought maybe asking, "Custom touchpad driver for windows, where do I start?" will give some answers that push you in the right direction. This seems to me to be the heart of your question. I think the research you have done on the problem already is making your main objective get a little lost. Hope my opinion helps, sorry I have no real input on your problem.

Comment: Damn! bounty worth 350 going in vein...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a msdn article about how you can map a [non-HID device to a HID device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163295.aspx) as part of the [Windows Touch Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee220483.aspx).

Also don't miss the general [driver developing tips](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/tips/default.mspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I saw this a little while back, but it took some time to figure out how to make it work for USB, since all their examples show mapping serial to HID.  However, I think I got it now.  Thanks again.